# Flask app not behaving as expected with dynamic list and tuples

Tags: python, flask

```
a = [2, 237, 3, 10]
b = (0, 0, {'product_id': '', 'product_uom_qty': ''}), (0, 0, {'product_id': '', 'product_uom_qty': ''})

start_index = 0
b = list(b)
for b_entry in b:
    end_endex = start_index + len(b_entry[2]) - 1
    for value in range(start_index, end_endex):
        b_entry[2]['product_id'] = a[value]
        b_entry[2]['product_uom_qty'] = a[value + 1]
    start_index += len(b_entry[2])
print(b)
```

works as desired and produces

```
[(0, 0, {'product_id': 2, 'product_uom_qty': 237}), (0, 0, {'product_id': 3, 'product_uom_qty': 10})]
```

however in a flask app

```
 @app.route('/listener', methods=['POST'])
def listener():
    if request.method == 'POST':


        content = request.json
        logging.info(content)


        invnm = content[0]['InvoiceNumber']
        fx = content[0]['InvoiceNumberPrefix']
        customer = content[0]['CustomerID']
        noi = (len(content[0]['OrderItemList']))


        itersandid = []
        changetos = {'672': 2,
             '333': 3}



        for d in content:
            for i in d["OrderItemList"]:
                itersandid.append(i.get("ItemID"))
                itersandid.append(i.get("ItemQuantity"))

        a = [changetos.get(x, x) for x in itersandid]
        sales = (0, 0, {'product_id':'','product_uom_qty':''}),
        b = []
        b.extend(sales*noi)
        print(a)
        print(b)


        start_index = 0
        b = list(b)
        for b_entry in b:
            end_endex = start_index + len(b_entry[2]) - 1
            for value in range(start_index, end_endex):
                b_entry[2]['product_id'] = a[value]
                b_entry[2]['product_uom_qty'] = a[value + 1]
            start_index += len(b_entry[2])
        print(b)
```

this happens

```
[(0, 0, {'product_id': 3, 'product_uom_qty': 10}), (0, 0, {'product_id': 3, 'product_uom_qty': 10})]
```

The results should be the same, I do not understand why they are not. I have printed both a and b and confirmed they are correct, but there must be an issue with the indexing but I am not sure what it could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the problem is right here:

```
sales = (0, 0, {'product_id':'','product_uom_qty':''}),
b = []
b.extend(sales*noi)
```

`{'product_id':'','product_uom_qty':''}` is one object and you don't clone it, just copy its reference that way. So the for loop changes the same instance at every iteration. That's why you have results of the last iteration in every copy.

Quick fix:

```
b = [(0, 0, {'product_id':'','product_uom_qty':''}) for _ in range(noi)]
```

Your example works because because you declare it like that:

```
b = (0, 0, {'product_id': '', 'product_uom_qty': ''}), (0, 0, {'product_id': '', 'product_uom_qty': ''})
```

You initialize two different objects, so it works as intented.

That was very tricky problem, thanks for the puzzle :)

Bonus: if you want to prove that in fact it's the same object you can paste this code in both fragments:

```
print(id(b[0][2]))
print(id(b[1][2]))
```

Comment: WOW, THANK YOU THANK YOU. I would have never figured this out, for other suffering similar issues, this is the only solution.

Comment: @hedgethenight I'm legitly surprised I figured it out. It's a really weird problem. In the future, prefer to build objects as late as possible. Less footguns in code ;)